# Can PostCSS resolve SASS-like syntax "#{$Interpolation}" code correctly

Tags: css, sass, postcss

I have read almost all of [PostCSS Plugins](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) and tried lots of ways to resolve codes below:

```
.component {
  $c: &;
  padding: 2vw;
  &__card {
    background-color: #fff;
    &:hover #{$c}__name {
      color: #bada55;
    }
  }
  &__name {
    color: #000;
  }
  &__button {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

But failed, `precss` seems to be a good solution, but also resolved not correct.

It compiled result like this:

```
.component {
  padding: 2vw;
}
  .component__card {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .component__card:hover .component__card__name {
      color: #bada55;
    }
  .component__name {
    color: #000;
  }
  .component__button {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

That obvious wrong, you can test sass code online http://sass.js.org/, what I expect result should be:

```
.component {
  padding: 2vw;
}
.component__card {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.component__card:hover .component__name {
  color: #bada55;
}
.component__name {
  color: #000;
}
.component__button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

How can I fix error with **postcss**? Is there any plugins can compile corrected?

> reference
>
> - [sass syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)
> - [How to do SASS Grandparent Selectors](https://codeburst.io/how-to-do-sass-grandparent-selectors-b8666dcaf961)